# Jade template to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

In a Jade file, how can I write something like this:

```
script. // Jade
 $('button').on('cick', function(){
  $('div').append(
   extend template // Jade
  );
 });
```

Where "template" is a block saved in a separate file somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It should work to skip the `.` and use `|` instead.

```
script // Jade
 | $('button').on('cick', function(){
 |  $('div').append(
   extend template // Jade
 |  );
 | });
```